# College of Science or College of Sciences

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I want to issue a certificate for a college. But, I am confused whether to write college of science or college of sciences. Should science be in singular or plural form?

Best regards,
Khalif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the college's *name*. The question is not one of grammar, but just finding out what the name actually is.

Some colleges are called, for example "The College of Science, University of Lincoln".  Some are called, for example "The College of Sciences, North Carolina State University"

Unfortunately, some colleges don't seem to know what their name actually is. [Khalifa University](http://www.ku.ac.ae/pages/college-of-science) uses "College of Arts and Sciences" as the heading, but then refer to the "College of Arts and Science".

So all you need to do is find what the name is. You don't need to worry about meaning or grammar. To do that, visit the website of the college and copy exactly what they have there.

Comment: Thank you James for the clarification. Yes, you are right. I searched on the internet and found both cases. So, I was confused which one I should use. But, now it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You may issue your certificate in the singular or the plural.

However, if a number of sciences were taught at the college (chemistry, physics, biology etc) it would be more accurate to use the plural.

**Science** in the singular is generally used as a catchword for sciences in general or an approach to gaining knowledge.

Wikipedia offers us the following definition: *Science (from Latin scientia, meaning "knowledge")is a systematic enterprise that builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable explanations and predictions about the universe.

So if your college sets out to teach pupils about science in general rather than its specific disciplines, then it might be more appropriate to use the singular.

Journals frequently use **Science** as a heading on a page that carries reports on a wide variety of scientific news.

Your choice should depend on what the college offers.

https://www.theguardian.com/science

Comment: Thank you Ronald for the explanation. It helped me a lot.